# how i can get number of online user in angular4

Tags: angular, signalr

I work in Angular4 ,Asp.netcore2 and JWToken. I  want get number of online user in my project .I use from signalR. I do not Know How get online User in component of angular. 
you can help me?
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use some sort of analytic tools, like [Google Analytics](https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/) to keep track of online users and which pages they are acessing.

I presume you are using stateless authentication because JWT. So to keep track of this information in your server you need to maintain the session state somewhere. Which i think you don't want to.

Answer (score 0):

This is a server side issue and this link is helpful 
[Online Users, Streaming and Other SignalR Goodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt847189.aspx)

Since the signalR use the websocket you can use this link 
[angular2websocket](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-websocket)
or google search about    websocket in angular